# All characters after closing square bracket ']' ignored by SAX parser

Tags: java, string, escaping, sax

Perhaps this is a general String/escape character issue, but I am having an issue with the characters() method in the DefaultHandler class of a SAX parser implementation.

If I have an XML node, for example:

```
<target type="xpath">//input[@id='txtPassword']</target>
```

And then attempt to print the string using the characters() method of the DefaultHandler Class, for example:

```
@Override
public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException { 
System.out.println("THIS IS THE STRING " + new String(ch, start, length)); 
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
THIS IS THE STRING //input[@id='txtPassword'
```

All characters including/after the closing square bracket are ignored. Another example:

```
<target type="xpath">//input[@id='txtPassword']abcd</target>
THIS IS THE STRING //input[@id='txtPassword'
```

I have tried escaping the character using [ and this doesn't work. Where
am I going wrong?? Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks all.

Tim

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting another call to `characters` later? IIRC, text nodes don't have to be reported in one chunk.

Comment: Thanks Jon, you were right! For anyone else who comes across this issue I used this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15755991/sax-parser-stringbuilder-only-returning-one-line) to help